# Finding logical connective corresponding to given fun :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool

Tags: haskell

The following questions appear in a mock exam and i cannot understand how the answers came about.
Anyone care to derive a method of calculating the answer as a similar set of questions will appear in an exam tomorrow.

Match each function definition with the logical operation it implements 
Question    Correct Match   Selected Match

```
funA x True = x
funA _ _    = False
-- Correct A.   Logical AND


funB x False = x
funB x True  = not x
-- Correct B.   Exclusive OR


funC False _ = True
funC True x  = x
-- Correct C. Logical IMPLICATION

funD x False = x
funD _ True  = True
-- Correct D.  Logical (Inclusive) OR


funE x True  = x
funE x False = not x
-- Correct E.   Logical EQUIVALENCE
```

Comment: It's _absurd_ to try to close a question with a problem domain of just 16 (very simple) possible total functions under the close reason "too broad".

Comment: @AndrewC, I think it likely that people are choosing to close based on reasoning that does not relate to the narrow rules of the help center. The OP would probably be better off visiting the teacher during office hours than asking strangers online.

Answer (score 3):

The question is to match logical operations to functions implementing them.
One method is simply comparing the truth table for the logical connectives to
that of the functions.

For instance, AND:

```
x    y    x AND y
-----------------
F    F       F
F    T       F
T    F       F
T    T       T
```

matches

```
funA x True = x 
funA _ _ = False
```

as

```
x    y      funA x y
-------------------------
F    F         F
F    T         x == False
T    F         F
T    T         x == True
```

and similarly for the rest.

Another option is to observe that `x AND y` is true iff `x` is true and `y` is true, and see which function satisfies that.